# Javascript Toggle based on Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have an element:

```
<a href="#" type="link" class="button send" classAct="button send" classSel="button send pressed" label="encrypt" title="sendmessage" onclick="add_encryption();">Encrypt</a>
```

that when toggles via the below javascript, I want it to display as:

```
<a href="#" type="link" class="button send" classAct="button send" classSel="button send pressed" label="decrypt" title="sendmessage" onclick="add_encryption();">Decrypt</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function add_encryption() {
    document.getElementById('compose-subject').value = "[encrypt]";
}
</script>
```

The problem is I don't know how to write the toggle for it.

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of `compose-subject` for the code `document.getElementById('compose-subject')`? Also, why the jQuery tag?

Comment: @j08691 What jquery tag?

Comment: You added the jQuery tag to your question (javascript, jquery, toggle).

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle" type="link" class="button send" classAct="button send" classSel="button send pressed" label="encrypt" title="sendmessage" onclick="encryptdecrypt();">Encrypt</a>


<script type="text/javascript>

function encryptdecrypt() {

    if(document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML == 'Encrypt')
{
    document.getElementById('compose-subject').value = "[encrypt]";
    document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML == 'Decrypt';
}
else
{
// decrypt here
document.getElementById('compose-subject').value = "[decrypt]";
document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML == 'Encrypt';
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It adds the encrypt to the subject, but the toggle part doesn't work. It also doesn't change the Encrypt to Decrypt.

Comment: is anchor tag text updates to encrypt when you press encrypt?

Comment: Yes but doesn't react when clicked to decrypt.

Comment: Put alert and check on click of decrypt if block executes or else block?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked for toggling for `<a>` tag here is the code

```
<a href="#" id="toggle" type="link" class="button send" classact="button send" classsel="button send pressed" label="encrypt" title="sendmessage" onclick="encryptdecrypt(this);">Encrypt </a>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function encryptdecrypt(obj) {
        obj.innerText = obj.innerText == "Encrypt" ? "Decrypt" : "Encrypt";
    }

</script>
```

I cant understand what is ''compose-subject'' assuming that its another element in the page, u can change the value of it using innerText and getElementById